# How can I install Ubuntu Desktop on Ubuntu app on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 Microsoft Store on Windows 10 version 2004 and I want to experience the GUI of Ubuntu instead of using shell.

How can I install GUI for Ubuntu app?

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to try it with WSL (which I still don't recommend) you can find the solution in this article [Gnome Desktop on WSL](https://superuser.com/questions/1305738/using-gnome-desktop-on-windows-wsl-version-of-ubuntu) which I still won't recommend, I personally have no experience installing it and do not know if installing X can break Windows Display Server. VM is still much more comfortable and safer way.
You also can try to use some graphical apps without having the whole DE installed. it will require installation of X server as well: [Running linux apps in WSL](https://www.howtogeek.com/261575/how-to-run-graphical-linux-desktop-applications-from-windows-10s-bash-shell/)

Yet again, all of that will not give you the same experience as a VM. My advice - go with VM, it's easy to install and configure. It's not so fast and smooth as a hardware installation (the same applies for any OS) but it's a good way to start.

Comment: The OP probably meant `ubuntu-desktop` which is a matapackage in the repositories. Anyway, your answer doesn't seem to answer the question directly, but rather expands into an essay on the subject of available DEs. Only the penultimate paragraph is relevant, but it makes little sense.